# Editing bst file to add "page" or "pages"

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I've got this bst file http://pastebin.com/z6mXByj7 and am using this tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,letterpaper,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>.}}
\decimalpoint %\spanishdecimal{.}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{ulem}
\def\bbluline#1{\uline#1}

\begin{document}
asdasd \citep{chsh_inequality} asdasd \citep*{aspect_test_bell}
\bibliographystyle{fiuady3}
\bibliography{ejem_biblio}

\end{document}
```

with this bib file

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.5.
% Encoding: Cp1252


@ARTICLE{chsh_inequality,
   author = {{Clauser}, J.~F. and {Horne}, M.~A. and {Shimony}, A. and {Holt}, R.~A.
    },
    title = "{Proposed Experiment to Test Local Hidden-Variable Theories}",
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
     year = 1969,
    month = oct,
   volume = 23,
   number = 15,
    pages = {880-884},
      doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.880},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1969PhRvL..23..880C},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{aspect_test_bell,
   author = {{Aspect}, A. and {Grangier}, P. and {Roger}, G.},
    title = "{Experimental Tests of Realistic Local Theories via Bell's Theorem}",
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
 keywords = {Fluorescence, phosphorescence},
     year = 1981,
    month = aug,
   volume = 47,
   number = 15,
    pages = {460-463},
      doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.47.460},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981PhRvL..47..460A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

which produces the following output [image]

that is exactly what I need except for the fact that it should place the particle for pages "pp" before 460-460 and 880-884. Can this be done by editing the bst file?

Comment: By the way, why do you load `babel` twice?

Comment: Uhhh well, I'm relatively new to latex, and still have a tendency to use other people's code blindly. I hadn't noticed.

Comment: Yes that can be done by editing the .bst file.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the definition of the function `format.journal.pages` as follows

```
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " * 
          swap$ pop$
          format.pages *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Notice that this works only for entries of type `article`.

Comment: I suppose that the function `format.pages` should be modified.

Comment: That returned to me the following errors after bibtex
`ptr=1, stack=
\textbf{80},pp 2245--2248
---the literal stack isn't empty for entry wooters_cocurrence
while executing---line 1586 of file fiuady.bst
(There were 18 error messages)`

Comment: I have updated the code. Does it work?

Comment: @Herbert Modifying `format.pages` would not work in this case (unless very heavy modifications of the whole style). The in `article` the  function `format.journal.pages` is used instead of `format.pages` and `format.journal.pages` takes care if other elements (journal number) is present. One has to do similar modification to the special functions used for the various entry types to output the pages.

Answer (score 0):

In my .bst file, I have the `bbl.pages` and `bbl.page` functions, which control the pre-formatting for references containing single and multiple pages.

```
FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "p." }
```

These functions can be modified from from `pp.` to `Pages:`, and, `p.` to `Page:` respectively, as follows:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "Pages:" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "Page:" }
```

To appreciate how this will effect your final document, the functions `bbl.pages` and `bbl.page`, above, are later called in the `format.pages` function:

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          bbl.pages swap$
          n.dashify
        }
        {
          bbl.page swap$
        }
      if$
      tie.or.space.prefix
      "pages" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}
```

In the `format.pages` function, after firstly checking whether the *pages* field is empty (skipping if true), it then checks whether single or multiple pages are involved (`multi.page.check`), calling the `bbl.page` and `bbl.pages` functions respectively.

Comment: In the provided bst style the function `format.pages` is the same as what you have. The issue is that `article` calls `format.jornal.pages` which calls `format.pages` when there is no volume number, but format directly the page numbers without inserting the page abbreviation ("pp" or "p").

Comment: @Guido, where is the switch based on no volume number?

Comment: If you look at the function `format.journal.pages` you can see that it puts `pages` on the stack, it duplicates it, and it the values is empty it removes it. Otherwise, it swaps `pages` with the previous element on the stack (and it is an educated guess from the output that it is the volume number), it duplicates it and check if it is empty. If it is it remove the last two elements from the stack (`pop$ pop$`), where, now, the second last is `pages` and then executes `format.pages`. Then we have the branch where there is value of pages, and there is a value for the previous element.